# Google map V2 wont show on API 23 but works fine on lower APIs

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm facing a strange behaviour, I'm developing an app that contains 4 fragments and one activity.

1º and 2º Fragments simply retrivr info from web apis(weather and events)
3º Fragment is just a layout for buttons
4º Is a google map V2 fragment

Everything works fine on phone/emulator with an api lower to 23. The fragments show up, the fragments retrivr the information they need to, and the maps works fine

The moment i try to test on a phone/emulator with an api 23, not even one fragment shows up. I just get the toolbar(which doesnt show on the any other api) and a white screen.

On my gradle i have minsdk version api 16 and target 23.
Do any of you know why this happens?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Note: If your app is targeting API level 23 (Android 6.0), which requires the use of runtime permissions, you should target version 8.3 or later of the Google Play services SDK.

Comment: in my gradle i have 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'

So if i understand correctly thats not the issue here right? By this two lines i make sure that i have the most recent SDK version, in this particular case the maps and location, which are the ones that i actually need

Comment: that sounds good, what about run time permissions?

Comment: I had that, what would happen was that it would ask for permission(as aspected), but when i pressed allow, it wont show anything anyway. After that I moved on little bit with the project and removed that. But i guess that isnt also the issue, because if that was the problem the app would crash and in the report i would get "SecurityException" or something like that (that happen the first time i tried without asking for permissions). But now i dont get any error message, the fragments simply dont show.